# AWS - What is the simplest way to get a dump of all allowed inbound IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Pretty new to the AWS APIs/Lambda so apologies if I'm missing something simple.  I just want to get an automated dump of the inbound IP addresses under each of our security groups on a weekly interval.  Is this something I can setup under lambda or do I need to do it through the API or CLI?   I've looked at the DescribeSecurityGroup functions under https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSecurityGroups.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html, but am wondering if I'm overcomplicating.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write an AWS Lambda function that queries the security groups for CIDR rules, using the AWS SDK for whatever programming language you are writing the Lambda function in. Then you could write the output to a file in the `/tmp` folder of the AWS Lambda environment, and then copy that file to S3 using the AWS SDK. Then you would schedule the Lambda function to run weekly.

If you already have an EC2 instance running on AWS then the "simplest" way would probably be to add a cron job to that instance that uses the AWS CLI tool to query for the CIDR rules.